# css selecting a lot of ids classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select a lot of different ids and classes. For example:

```
<div id="a b c d" class="e f g h i j ">Red text</div>
#a.#b.#c.#d.e.f.g.h.i.j{color:red;}
```

Also tried:

```
#a#b#c#d.e.f.g.h.i.j{color:red;}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vHvm9/

This doesn't work. Doesn't CSS support that much selection or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: a single element cannot have multiple IDs.

Comment: *ID* makes element **unique** so your design of multi ids makes no sense.. anyway element cant have more than one *ID*

Comment: And, finally, you don't have to name _all_ classes of an element to select it. So in your example selecting for example by class 'e' would have been enough: `.e{color:red;}`. A more precise selector is only required if you have to be more precise.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SqDnA/1/ is a corrected version of your fiddler: as you can see it works when you use only a single id for an element.

Answer (score 3):

As far as CSS is concerned, your second selector `#a#b#c#d.e.f.g.h.i.j` is valid and you could *theoretically* match an element with multiple IDs in CSS. But this will only work if the DOM actually allows an element to have that many IDs in the first place. In HTML, spaces don't separate ID names like they do class names; an HTML element can have only at most one ID specified by an `id` attribute, and that ID isn't supposed to contain spaces (even though a browser will happily take it if you feed it such bad markup anyway).

You can still assign other IDs to a single element by other means (again, if the DOM allows it), but there is absolutely no practical reason to unless you're working with some obscure markup language where having multiple IDs means something.

So, to answer your question: what you're doing wrong is attempting to assign multiple IDs to an element at all. Just assign one ID without any whitespace in its value, and select by that ID.

Answer (score 2):

As Jan pointed out single element cannot have multiple IDs in HTML or XML.

But if you will find host language (for CSS) that supports multiple IDs then you should use correct CSS selector:

```
#a#b#c#d.e.f.g.h.i.j{color:red;}
```

Comment: Not sure if that is what you really want to express. This example states that the element has to have all ids and all classes as mentioned in the selector.

Comment: @arkascha: `div#c` but not `div.#c`

Comment: @arkascha: The answer is saying that one of the selectors he tried is wrong, and even if he uses the correct one it will only work with a host language that supports elements with multiple IDs and classes in the first place (which neither HTML nor XML are).

Comment: @BoltClock I did understand what the purpose of this answer is. And indeed it makes sense to hint that there are applications of css apart from html markup. Still I fail to make any sense from the comment c-smile made...

Comment: Ah, ok, he is referring to the notation inside the fiddler! Wouldn't have hurt to say so, would it?